# how to get result number in fetch

Tags: php

I have Cats and I have posts, this my code :

```
<?php
        $sel_query = "SELECT * FROM cats ORDER BY cat_id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

        {  // start insert cats

        echo "<h1>Cat Name: ".$data["cat_id"]."</h1>";

            $sel_query2 = "SELECT * FROM selecom WHERE cel_cat='".$data['cat_id']."' ";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query2);
            while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 

                {    // start insert posts
                    echo "<h2>Post: ".$data2['cel_golid']."</h2>";
                    echo "<h2>total Post Numbers in this cat: ?????????????????????????????????</h2>";
                }
        }
?>
```

i need insert total Post Numbers (Place question marks)

Example:
If there are 2 posts in a some cat, I want to write the number of posts in (place of question marks) 2

*I apologize if the translation is unclear

Comment: did you try $result2->num_rows; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
$result2->num_rows
```

See the documentation: 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

check the below URL, your doubt may clarify

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp